# How do you track display impressions in Google Analytics on non Google networks?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, impressions

Google Analytics has a Multi-Channel funnel analysis feature that we’d like to use to understand assisted conversions and how each channel has impacted on conversion beyond just last interaction attribution.

My current understanding is that the impression tracking part of this feature works really well when playing within Google’s search and display networks. Outside of Google’s network I suspect that impression tracking will no longer “just work” and feed back into GA appropriately.

What our options are for tracking display impressions on other advertising networks so that we can be attributing value correctly with GA?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has a [cost data upload](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/cost-data-import) feature that is designed so that you can have cost and impression data for your campaigns in Google Analytics.

The input must be in a properly formatted CSV file with at least the following columns (there are also optional columns listed):

- ga:source (matching the campaign source (`utm_source`))
- ga:medium (matching the campaign medium (`utm_medium`))
- ga:adCost
- ga:adClicks
- ga:impressions

All the data in a particular CSV file are assumed to be for the same date, so it appears that you have to be prepared to upload a new CSV file every day.